# Plone email out errors from error_log

Tags: plone, zope

What would be the best way to get email notifications from error_log errors? For ultra fast responsive times in the case of site really needs someone to watch after it.

Any other notification recommendations?

Comment: Yes, see the answer re mailinglogger there.

Comment: Trying to close my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use logbook:

http://plone.org/products/collective.logbook